# Yii2: function in SQL query

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I need to select persons that have 21 old years old or less from a table called **persons** using the Yii2 framework.

**persons = (id, birthdate)**

```
public static function findByBirthday($idper) {
    $query = Persons::find()
        ->select([
            Persons::tableName().".[[id]]", 
            Persons::tableName().".[[birthday]]"
        ])
        ->where([
            '<=',
            'select age(birthday, NOW())',
            21
        ])

    return $query->asArray()->all();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code  ..?  you have error?   .. show the exact error msg  .. wrong result  .. add  a proper data sample the actual result and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the birthday is valid  DATE type

```
public static function findByBirthday($idper) {
    $query = Persons::find()
        ->select([
            Persons::tableName().".[[id]]", 
            Persons::tableName().".[[birthday]]"
        ])
        ->where([
            '<=',
            'EXTRACE(year from age(birthday))',
            21
        ])

    return $query->asArray()->all();
}
```

or

```
  ->where(   'EXTRACE(year from age(birthday))   <= 21')
```

Comment: I do not think that would work, you probably have to use `new yii\db\Expression('EXTRACE(year from age(birthday))'),` instead of  `'EXTRACE(year from age(birthday))',`

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare `birthday` with date from 21 years ago - it should better reuse indexes than  expression for age calculation and result will be the same.

```
public static function findByBirthday($idper) {
    $query = Persons::find()
        ->select([
            Persons::tableName() . ".[[id]]",
            Persons::tableName() . ".[[birthday]]",
        ])
        ->where([
            '>=',
            'birthday',
            new Expression('date :date', [
                ':date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-21 years')),
            ]),
        ]);

    return $query->asArray()->all();
}
```